# Slow Euclidean Distance

Tags: python, numpy, knn

I am calculating Euclidean Distance with python code below:

```
def getNeighbors(trainingSet, testInstance, k, labels):
    distances = []
    for x in range(len(trainingSet)):
        dist = math.sqrt(((testInstance[0] - trainingSet[x][0]) ** 2) +    ((testInstance[1] - trainingSet[x][1]) ** 2))
        distances.append([dist, labels[x]])
    distances = np.array(distances)   
    return distances
```

For calculating distance of a given point with 10 other points, it's good. But when I calculate distance of a point with 18563 other points, then the computer gets hanged and don't response for around 3 Hrs.

**How can I make calculation for** 18563 **points faster?**

Comment: you may use `math.hypot(x, y)` instead of `dist = math.sqrt(((testInstance[0] - trainingSet[x][0]) ** 2) +    ((testInstance[1] - trainingSet[x][1]) ** 2))`, and `xrange`instead of `range`

Comment: Are you doing anything that might require pairwise distances, or are you only calculating distances to one distinguished point? Pairwise distances for 18563 points are going to take a lot longer, simply because there are about 172 million of them to calculate.

Comment: I am taking one example and calculating it's distances with other points.

Comment: Don't use for loops to do heavy lifting (in python). Either vectorize so you can numpy or use something different like cython or numba.

Comment: Can you give a [complete minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of just this function on its own? Because if you're just calling this once, even with a list of 18563 points, it really shouldn't take long at all. It's not clear what you _are_ doing that's taking 3 hours, but the little 5% optimizations that people can make to just this code in isolation aren't going to help (except to reduce it to 2 hours and 51 minutes).

Comment: Even if converting the loop to NumPy makes it, say, 12x as fast, it's still taking 15 minutes instead of the fraction of a second it should take…

Comment: One more thing: Any chance that your vmsize is larger than your system's physical RAM? If so, every time you iterate a large object, or just access something you haven't accessed in a while, you're probably swapping memory pages to and from disk, which will slow the whole program (and your whole computer) down by a few orders of magnitude. If that's the problem, the best way to speed it up is (somewhat ironically) to focus on reducing space instead of time.

Comment: And one more one-more-thing: Have you tried just running your existing code in PyPy instead of CPython? That tends to get you the same kind of order-of-magnitude constant speedup as NumPy (and occasionally it'll get you a 1000000x speedup, which tells you that all the heavy lifting you're doing in some loop can be lifted out of that loop…), and changing the `#!` line is even less work than rewriting your loops as elementwise operators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can speed this up by converting to NumPy first, then using vector operations, instead of doing the work in a loop, then converting to NumPy. Something like this:

```
trainingArray = np.array(trainingSet)
distances = ((testInstance[0] - trainingArray[:, 0]) ** 2 +
             (testInstance[1] - trainingArray[:, 1]) ** 2).sqrt()
```

(That's obviously untested, because without enough context to know what's actually in those variables I had to guess, but it will be something close to that.)

There are other things you can do to squeeze out a few extra %—try replacing the `** 2` with self-multiplication or the `sqrt` with `** .5`, or (probably best) replacing the whole thing with `np.hypot`. (If you don't know how to use [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)—or, even better, IPython and it's `%timeit` magic—now is a great time to learn.)

But ultimately, this is just going to give you a constant-multiplier speedup of about an order of magnitude. Maybe it takes 15 minutes instead of 3 hours. That's nice, but… why is it taking 3 hours in the first place? What you're doing here should be taking on the order of seconds, or even less. There's clearly something much bigger wrong here, like maybe you're calling this function N**2 times when you think you're only calling it once. And you really need to fix that part.

Of course it's still worth doing this. First, element-wise operations are simpler and more readable than loops, and harder to get wrong. Second, even if you reduce the whole program to 3.8 seconds, you'll be happy for the order-of-magnitude speedup to 0.38 seconds, right?

Comment: what is `trainingArray` for ?

Comment: @user2831683: It's a NumPy `array` with the same elements as are in the `list` or `set` or whatever in `trainingSet`. By making it a NumPy `array` instead of a native Python collection, we can do NumPy slicing—and, more importantly, NumPy vectorized operations.

Comment: I meant, you aren't using it.

Comment: is this faster than using np.hypot()?

Comment: @paddyg: Probably not, but it's probably a tiny difference, and it should be a lot easier for the OP to understand how this is equivalent to his code. I've edited it to mention `np.hypot`, but I don't think it's that important here.

Comment: @abarnert in answer to my own question, for 18563 points: `** 0.5` and `np.sqrt()` take 0.77ms `np.hypot()` and self multiplication (instead of `** 2`) take 1.14ms. Obviously your other points are the critical step here (both these values are effectively instantaneous c.f. 3h) but interesting to know when squeezing the last bit of speed out.

Comment: @paddyg: Wait, your optimizations actually make it 48% _slower_? I wouldn't have expected that. Well, that's why you test. :)

Comment: @paddyg: Anyway, I still think there's something _else_ wrong here outside the code he's shown us. From a quick&dirty test with a made-up guess at the data, his original code took only 38ms, which may be 1 or 2 orders of magnitude slower than with NumPy, but it's _still_ effectively instantaneous, and certainly not hours…

Comment: finally, calculation gets completed in around 11 secs. I used this and replaced loops with numpy equivalents and also used `** 2` and `** 0.5` instead of `math.pow` and `math.sqrt`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Writing own sqrt calculator has its own risks, hypot is very safe for resistance to overflow and underflow

```py
x_y = np.array(trainingSet)
x = x_y[0]
y = x_y[1]
distances = np.hypot(
    np.subtract.outer(x, x),
    np.subtract.outer(y, y)
)
```

Speed wise they are same

```
%%timeit
np.hypot(i, j)
# 1.29 µs ± 13.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
np.sqrt(i**2+j**2)
# 1.3 µs ± 9.87 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

### Underflow

```py
i, j = 1e-200, 1e-200
np.sqrt(i**2+j**2)
# 0.0
```

### Overflow

```py
i, j = 1e+200, 1e+200
np.sqrt(i**2+j**2)
# inf
```

### No Underflow

```py
i, j = 1e-200, 1e-200
np.hypot(i, j)
# 1.414213562373095e-200
```

### No Overflow

```py
i, j = 1e+200, 1e+200
np.hypot(i, j)
# 1.414213562373095e+200
```

[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69233365/7035448)